"Oh there is scraping sounding." VS "Oh there is a scraping sound."
A British person is walking round the house, and when she gets upstairs, she hears continuing sounds as if a construction worker is scraping on a wall. So she is suprised and says:
"Oh there is scraping sounding." Half term adventures (see:12:48-12:53)
This usage seemed unusual to me, because it seems like a shortened form of "There is scraping, which is sounding", which would not be natural usage. What I would say as a non-native speaker:
"Oh there is a scraping sound."
Would my usage not be correct?

Native speakers don't always talk like your school book, especially when they are making Youtube videos. What she said is an acceptable understandable informal usage. In fact what she said is 'Oooh, there's a scraping sounding'. She is making up what she says as she goes along, keeping up her vocal fry, trying to film herself with a selfie stick and walk around the house all at the same time. People often make little mistakes in that sort of situation. She started off talking like a posh Southerner but from time to time her Yorkshire roots show through.

It is decidedly unusual, but, as Michael says, people speaking off-the cuff do say odd things sometimes. Note that British (and other nationalities) take a capital letter.

@MichaelHarvey, perfect explanation.

@KateBunting, thanks Kate for the comment. I corrected the lower case "b".

I’m voting to close this question because it's a minor mistake made in unrehearsed speech, there is no English Learning to be found here.

On a psychological note, this is not "a scraping sound" but "a (rehab activity of) scraping sounding".  In other words, I can hear that there's some rehab work going on.

It is a tad usual because of the bare participle sounding. But it's not a "shortened form" of "There is scraping, which is sounding".  A participial clause is another way of complementing the noun-like word "scraping".
You could phone the plumber and say:

There's a dripping coming from inside the wall in the bathroom.

"a dripping" can have the practical meaning of a "drip drip drip sound".
Compare:

There was a coat hanging on a peg in the foyer.

